# CKEditor - Add a custom right click menu to certain element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How would I go about adding a custom context menu to CKEditor?

I'm building a simple website editor for a resturant and they need to be able to edit the menu. I've added a button that adds a custom table, how could I have it so when they right click they can choose to add one of two options (which would either be category row, or menu row)

I know there are many questions about adding and removing options from the context menu, but I want to have a custom context menu that pops up if a user right clicks on that specific table with a certain class

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I haven't come across anything other than having a separate menuGroup for every table cell, and using some element.getId() hackery :-(

Comment: I never did unfortunately.. Please let me know if you ever find anything! I really want to update the clients website :)